# A totally bounded uniformity and certain filters

Tags: set-theory, filters, uniform-spaces

**Conjecture** For every totally bounded uniform space $(U;F)$ and filters $\mathcal{X}$, $\mathcal{Y}$ on $U$ such that $$\forall E\in F,X\in\mathcal{X},Y\in\mathcal{Y}:(X\times Y)\cap E\ne\emptyset,$$

there exist proper filters $\mathcal{X}'\supseteq\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}'\supseteq\mathcal{Y}$ such that $$\forall E\in F \exists X'\in\mathcal{X}', Y'\in\mathcal{Y}':X'\times Y'\subseteq E.$$

Comment: Oops, I've corrected an error in the second displayed formula (and yet one more error in the same formula)

Comment: To clarify, should the first displayed line be $\forall E\ \forall X\ \forall Y$ and the second one be $\forall E\ \exists X'\  \exists Y'$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I think it is correct. However I asked this question almost a two years ago and may not remember the context of the issue.